# ASP AJAX Extensions in Win 2008 not working when deployed using IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to publish a website using IIS7 from Win 2008 R2 server. Everything works fine but  AJAX extensions from visual studio does not work. It works perfectly when you run using visual studio but  when website is launched using IIS7, page does not refresh itself as it needs to be. I know I am missing  ext. files or some statement in web.config just trying to figure out what is it? I am using framework 4.0 and VS 2010 professional. It is not giving me any errors but just not refreshing the page. Also, I have downloaded AJAX extenstions 1.0

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Have you compared the `web.config` of your "working" version in Visual Studio to the one deployed to see what is missing?

Comment: Yes Karl, I have. It's exactly the same. Do I need to add something in Web config in order update my components @update panel automatically? Do I need to add: what this link say?http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21372/Adding-ASP-NET-AJAX-to-an-Existing-ASP-NET-Applica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is: run AJAX 1.0 setup before while implementing IIS7. Also, include  include ISCAPI and CGI components for IIS7 . Website will have AJAX working.